how to get different filenames in chunk files after build in nextjs14 to avoid cache?
After each build I want the chunk files generated has different names.
Example:
<link rel="preload" as="script" fetchPriority="low" href="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-653a0787c4442713.js"/>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-1a173cac11a1f73c.js" async=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/23-5b35c9eea0c04c88.js" async=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-app-f12028dd9bfdf9fd.js" async=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/223-58572653937c7966.js" async=""></script>

"main-app-{.....}.js" is cached in my server side and after each build I've problems with user render side.

Why not just invalidate the cache? How are you caching?

i need the cache for SEO stuff :( so en each build i need to change the variables yes or yes!

What i'm trying to say is that  invalidate cache is a common task and changing build artifacts name not so mutch. invalidate cache does not mean to remove cache, but to just clean it once something happen.

@vzsoares i'm using cloudflare to clean cache, and rm the .next folder after build, but it seems is not the better way. All the users using nextjs has the same problems

Sorry but i've never heard of that problem, cache invalidation works just fine for me. Can you share a source for "All the users using nextjs has the same problems"?
